# How do I get the inode number of the current process's executable inside kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel

In Linux v0.11 `task_struct` had an `executable` member of type `m_inode *`. I am looking for something similar.

Does the exec/execve system call store this information anywhere or is it lost upon loading into memory?

Answer (score 2):

There's no direct link like that anymore.  The `proc_exe_link()` function gets this information by looking for the first executable vma in the task that is mapping a file.  You would do that for `current` with something like:

```
struct dentry *dentry = NULL;
struct vfsmount *mnt = NULL;
struct vm_area_struct * vma;

down_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);

vma = current->mm->mmap;
while (vma) {
    if ((vma->vm_flags & VM_EXECUTABLE) && vma->vm_file)
        break;
    vma = vma->vm_next;
}

if (vma) {
    mnt = mntget(vma->vm_file->f_path.mnt);
    dentry = dget(vma->vm_file->f_path.dentry);
}

up_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);

if (dentry) {
    /* inode is dentry->d_inode */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not lost, of course. Just that in recent Linux kernel, it is a bit complex to track it.

For a recent Linux kernel, With a pointer of 'struct task_struct', you first need to get the 'struct mm_struct', by:

```
    mm = get_task_mm(task);
```

and then

```
    exe_file = get_mm_exe_file(mm);
```

now you have the 'struct file' pointer to the exec file, with 'struct file', you can get its inode by:

```
    struct inode *inode = file->f_path.dentry->d_inode;
```

BTW, the definition of get_mm_exe_file() is

```
struct file *get_mm_exe_file(struct mm_struct *mm)
{       
        struct file *exe_file;

        /* We need mmap_sem to protect against races with removal of
         * VM_EXECUTABLE vmas */
        down_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
        exe_file = mm->exe_file;
        if (exe_file)
                get_file(exe_file);
        up_read(&mm->mmap_sem);
        return exe_file;
}
```